# React/Redux Component didnt render correctly

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am new to Redux , my problem is The Component can not be rendered and no any error msg shows , 
it shows correctly without applying redux when i just render Option1(variable),anyone help? thankyou !!!! Can anyone solve my problem with some coding example thx!

**Action**

```
function clickRaidoButt(id) {
    return {
        type: 'CLICK_RADIO',
        payload: id
    }
}
```

**Reducers**

```
function reducreForRadio(state = initialStateForRadio, action) {
    if (typeof state === 'undefined') {
        return 0
    }

    var id;

    switch(action.type) {
        case 'CLICK_RADIO': {
             return {
                 id: action.payload
             }
        }
        default: {
             return state
        }
    }
}
```

**Component**

```
var Option1 = React.createClass({


    render() {
        const { id } = this.props;    

        return ( 
            <label>
                <input  
                    onClick={() => this.props.clickRaidoButt('option1')}  
                    type="radio" 
                    id="option1" 
                    name="selOption" 
                />
            </label>
        );
    }
});
```

**Mapping**

```
function mapDispatchToPropsForRaidoButt (dispatch) {
    return { 
        clickRaidoButt : (id) => dispatch(clickRaidoButt(id))
    };
}

function mapStateToPropsForRaidoButt(state) {  
    return {  
        id: state.reducreForRadio.id
    }  
}
```

**Connection**

```
var rootReducer = Redux.combineReducers({
    reducreForAge,
    reducreForButtonGroup2,
    reducreForRadio
});

const radio1 = connect(mapStateToPropsForRaidoButt,mapDispatchToPropsForRaidoButt)(Option1);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <radio1/>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('selOption1')
);
```

Comment: Any errors on warnings in console ?

Comment: It'll probably be helpful if you can workout how to reproduce this in codepen or something. It can be a bit fiddly - but I suggest googling something like 'react-redux boilerplate codepen'.

Comment: no any errors or warnings in console :(